# Assumption of normality while creating CI from chi-squared and t-statistic pivots?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

While explaining the use of a chi-squared pivot or a t-statistic in creating confidence interval, we were told that one of the underlying assumption is the normality of the data. Chi-squared distribution, as I understand it, is the distribution of any sum of squares of Normal RVs.

So while using it for variance, does not the Central Limit Theorem dictate that the sample mean $\bar X$, irrespective of the distribution of the original RV, will be distributed normally, and since the population mean ($ \mu $) is a constant, $ \bar X-\mu $ will be normally distributed and hence their squares should follow a chi-squared distribution? Where is the assumption of normality?
The same argument applies to a t-statistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1,..,X_n$ i.i.d $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ each one,hence by definition
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^2 \sim \chi^2_n \, .
$$
Now, in order to estimate the variance of the *Normal* distribution, you are using (variation of) 
$$
S^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2,
$$ 
thus 
$$
\sigma^2 S^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{X_i - \bar{X}}{\sigma}\right)^2 \sim \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \chi^2_{n-1}.
$$
For the construction of the CI you are using the fact that the estimator is distributed $\chi^2$ up to some constant term, i.e., 
$$
P\left(\chi^2_{n-1, \alpha/2} \le \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2 \le  \chi^2_{n-1, 1-\alpha/2} \right) = 1- \alpha
$$
or by simple manipulation you get the familiar form
$$
P\left(\chi^2_{n-1, \alpha/2} \le \frac{n}{\sigma^2} S^2\le  \chi^2_{n-1, 1-\alpha/2} \right) = 1- \alpha,
$$
since all the terms are positive and thus $g_1(x)=1/x$ and $g_2(x) = x^{1/2}$ are well defined one to one functions on $\mathbb{R}^+$, you get the final expression of 
$$
P\left(\sigma \in \left[\sqrt{nS^2/\chi^2_{n-1, 1-\alpha/2}}, \sqrt{nS^2/\chi^2_{n-1, \alpha/2}} \right] \right) = 1-\alpha.
$$
Note that all these manipulations are justified by the initial assumption of normality of the data $X_1,..., X_n$. With the $t$ distribution is the same idea, one of the possible ways to define it, is by
$$
T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{Q/n}},\,\, Q\sim \chi^2_n.
$$
So $(\bar{X}_n - \mu)/\sigma \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ only where $X_1,...,X_n$ is initially $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Particularly, the familiar result of 
$$
\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}\sim t,
$$
can be attained by simple algebra using the aforementioned definitions.   Note that the CLT is not required here as the results hold precisely and for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. When your original data is not normal you can use the CLT in order to deduce the asymptotic normality of $\bar{X}_n$. But in this case your distribution is only approximatelly normal and $n$ should be large enough, as such the use of $t$ may be redundant as the standard normal distribution will yield paractically the same results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a couple of clarifications. So, as I understand it, since the chi-squared involves the $X_i$ term along with the $\bar X_n$ which makes it distribution dependent, and so does the $S$ term in the popular formula for the t-statistic? Had, hypothetically, the definition of a pivot involved only the $\bar X_n$, would the resultant pivot be normality-independent, as $\bar X_n$ (the sample mean) has an already defined distribution?

Comment: And can you let me know how we came from the $\chi_n ^2$ to $\chi_{n-1} ^2$ in the original derivation.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but I'll try to answer it anyway. 
1. The reason for the $\chi^2$ distribution is the fact that $(X_i - \bar{X})/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_1$. The dependence between $X_i$ and $\bar{X}_n$ it is not the issue in the distribution determination but it is why the df decreases from $n$ to $n-1$. 
2. Do you mean can a pivotal quantity that is based solely on $\bar{X}_n$ define a non-normal distribution? Then sure, the normality of the sample mean (for non normal settings) is only an approximation,